# How to generate 6 digits multiple OTP and insert into database at once with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

**I am generating 6 digits random OTP in my `views.py` and I just want to insert those many OTPs to be inserted into my Table at once using single QuerySet.** *Here is my code:*

> home.html

```
<form class="" action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="" style="text-align: center:">
    Mobile : <input type="text" name="mobile" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate OTP">
  </div>
</form>
```

> models.py

```
class otpModel(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=True)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mobile
```

> views.py

```
import random
from app_name.models import otpModel

def registerOTP(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       mobile = request.POST['mobile']

       for i in range(100):
          otp = random.randint(100000, 999999)
          otp = otpModel.objects.create(mobile=mobile, otp=otp)
          if otp:
             messages.info(request, 'OTP is saved!!!')
             return render(request, 'app_name/otp.html')
   else:
       return render(request, 'studentexams/otp.html')
```

**Here whenever I enter the Mobile number in the HTML form then only 1 OTP is inserted in the Table. Is there any solutions that I can insert multiple OTPs at a time using single QuerySet**

*Please give the Code snippet for achieving this task to be done*

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
from itertools import islice
def registerOTP(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mobile = request.POST['mobile']
        otps = []
        for i in range(100):
            otp = random.randint(100000, 999999)
            otp_obj = otpModel(mobile=mobile, otp=otp)
            otps.append(opt_obj)
        # I advise you to do the following in a celery task
        # Doing it in the request thread is a bad User experience
        batch_size = 50  # 50 is the batch size, you
        # can change it to any number you want based on your usecase
        while True:
            batch = list(islice(otps, batch_size))
            if not batch:
                break
            otpModel.objects.bulk_create(batch, batch_size)
            del otps[0:batch_size]
        if otp:
            messages.info(request, 'OTP is saved!!!')
            return render(request, 'app_name/otp.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'studentexams/otp.html')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't explain you how much my time you saved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a manager method called `bulk_create`. Using this method you can create list of objects into the database.

bulk_create(objs, batch_size=None, ignore_conflicts=False)

Your code snippet will be like:

```
otpModel.objects.bulk_create([otpModel(mobile=mobile, otp=otp1),
                              otpModel(mobile=mobile, otp=otp2),
                             ])
```

This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are):

Example:

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
...     Entry(headline='This is a test'),
...     Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
... ])
```

You can check out the official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me your precious time